# Use a framework for security or do it by myself?

Tags: security, frameworks

I have this doubt since a while and today I'm not so strong a position, despite having taken one.

Whenever I develop or participate in the development of an application (WEB), typically treat security finger-and-nail, that is, we treat all processes related to security, sessions until encryption of passwords, etc.

I remember hearing someone say that it is always better to use a Framework (Spring, Apache Shiro, etc).

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is always better to use a framework rather then re-inventing the whole wheel again. I personally prefer Apache Shiro and have made customizations to suite my needs by extending classes provided.

REad here http://shiro.apache.org/

Some points to meke up your mids are:

**Custom code equals custom vulnerabilities:** With web applications you typically generate most of the application code yourself (even when using common frameworks and plugins). That means most vulnerabilities will be unique to your application. It also means that unless you are constantly evaluating your own application, there’s no one to tell you when a vulnerability is discovered in the first place.

**You are the vendor:** When a vulnerability appears, you won’t have an outside vendor providing a patch (you will, of course, have to install patches for whatever infrastructure components, frameworks, and scripting environments you use). If you provide external services to customers, you may need to meet any service level agreements you provide and must be prepared to be viewed by them just as you view your own software vendors, even if software isn’t your business. You have to patch your own vulnerabilities, deal with your own customer relations, and provide everything you expect from those who provide you with software and services.

**Reliance on frameworks/platforms**: We rarely build our web applications from the ground up in shiny new C code. We use a mixture of different frameworks, development tools, platforms, and off the shelf components to piece them together. We are challenged to secure and deploy these pieces as well as the custom code we build with and on top of them. In many cases we create security issues through unintended uses of these components or interactions between the multiple layers due to the complexity of the underlying code. When we can use for all other parts why not use for security and just keep and eye if any vurneability is found in that framework and respond by updating as community can update faster and better than by oneself.